# Button in view not clicking ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu in Swift by adding a view below the navigation bar and initially setting it to hidden until a navigationBarItem button is pressed, which works. In the dropdown View I have added two buttons as seen in the code below but it doesn't seem to pick up the event.

```
var isAnimating: Bool = false
var dropDownViewIsDisplayed : Bool = false
var dropDownView : UIView!

var buttonOne : UIButton!
var buttonTwo : UIButton!

var screenWidth : CGFloat!

@IBOutlet weak var searchNavigationBar: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
    dropDownView =  UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, -15, screenWidth, -80))

    dropDownView.hidden = true
    dropDownView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.navigationController?.view.insertSubview(self.dropDownView, belowSubview: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!)

    buttonOne = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 40))
    buttonOne.setTitle("Button One", forState: .Normal)
    buttonOne.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonOnePressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    buttonOne.userInteractionEnabled = true
    dropDownView.addSubview(buttonOne)

    buttonTwo = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, buttonOne.bounds.size.height, screenWidth, 40))
    buttonTwo.setTitle("Button Two", forState: .Normal)
    buttonTwo.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    buttonTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    buttonTwo.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTwoPressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    buttonTwo.userInteractionEnabled = true
    dropDownView.addSubview(buttonTwo)

}

func buttonTwoPressed(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLocation", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showLocation") {
        var location: LocationTableViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? LocationTableViewController)!

    }
}
```

Button click functions are not being called.

Comment: can you show `buttonOnePressed` function?

Comment: Please ensure that you do not have some transparent view on top of `UIButton` and that action button is not implemented as `buttonOnePressed:`

Comment: @bsarr007 updated to show function

Comment: do you have a visual feedback when you press on the buttons?

Comment: not at the moment, only using breakpoints and the debugger but the functions aren't being called.

Comment: Why do you have to add the buttons in navigationController?.view and not self.view ?

Comment: Try adding a `print()` function to check the buttons. `if buttonPressed { print("Hello Button") }`

Comment: could you try this `buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: "buttonOnePressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)` instead of `buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonOnePressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` and update me

Comment: @Rage the buttons are added to the dropdown view which is a added below the navigation bar

Comment: @WilliamKinaan thanks but same issue

Comment: @DrPatience add this function `override func layoutSubviews() { print("hi")}` to your code and tell me how many times the "hi" word was printed please

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Swift 2.0 with Xcode 7? Just by quickly tried playing with your code like this, I found that the event handlers are being called properly without any big changes. Are you sure that there is nothing wrong somewhere else?

```
var isAnimating: Bool = false
var dropDownViewIsDisplayed : Bool = false
var dropDownView : UIView!

var buttonOne : UIButton!
var buttonTwo : UIButton!

var screenWidth : CGFloat!

@IBOutlet weak var searchNavigationBar: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

   // I modified these 2 lines to test your code immediately
    dropDownView =  UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 65, screenWidth, 80))        
    dropDownView.hidden = false

    dropDownView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.navigationController?.view.insertSubview(self.dropDownView, belowSubview: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!)

    buttonOne = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 40))
    buttonOne.setTitle("Button One", forState: .Normal)
    buttonOne.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonOnePressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    buttonOne.userInteractionEnabled = true
    dropDownView.addSubview(buttonOne)

    buttonTwo = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, buttonOne.bounds.size.height, screenWidth, 40))
    buttonTwo.setTitle("Button Two", forState: .Normal)
    buttonTwo.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    buttonTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    // Here I just wanted to show you that calling Selector() is not necessary at all
    buttonTwo.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTwoPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    buttonTwo.userInteractionEnabled = true
    dropDownView.addSubview(buttonTwo)
}

// I didn't see this method in your code above so I added to test and it works!
func buttonOnePressed() {
    print("buttonOnePressed")
}
// This is also being called normally
func buttonTwoPressed() {
    print("buttonTwoPressed")
}
```

Comment: very odd it doesn't work on mine. Perhaps because the controller is a root controller of a navigation controller in the main story board ?

Comment: My view controller is also the root view controller of a navigation controller so it must not be the point. Could you share your code via GitHub?

Comment: hey thanks, I've sorted it out now. Had to do with the initial frame it was set to. Thanks for your pointers

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with:

```
buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonOnePressed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

buttonTwo.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTwoPressed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: After you shared your button handler code, I see you have implemented it correctly. Did u check if there is some transparent view covering buttons?

Comment: how do you check for that ? this controller is a root view controller of a navigation controller in the story board.

Answer (score 0):

It won't works because it outside `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame`. You should add buttons on `self.view` or transparent modal view/UIWindow.